# Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, decimal, mysql-error-1292

In MySQL 5.6.13 with SQL mode "`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`", the following query works ok, but with warnings:

```
UPDATE Company SET company_CurrentYearValueGBP = COALESCE((
SELECT SUM(
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month01Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month02Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month03Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month04Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month05Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month06Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month07Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month08Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month09Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month10Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month11Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
(COALESCE(salesdata_Month12Amount,0) / IF(salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'',salesdata_ExchangeRate,1) ) + 
0) FROM SalesData 
WHERE salesdata_SalesDataTypeID = 3 
AND salesdata_CompanyID = company_ID 
AND salesdata_SalesYearID = 6 
AND NOT salesdata_IsBeingProcessed 
),0)
```

**Output:**

```
0 row(s) affected, 5 warning(s):
 1265 Data truncated for column 'company_CurrentYearValueGBP' at row 127
 1265 Data truncated for column 'company_CurrentYearValueGBP' at row 127
 1265 Data truncated for column 'company_CurrentYearValueGBP' at row 127
 1265 Data truncated for column 'company_CurrentYearValueGBP' at row 127
 1265 Data truncated for column 'company_CurrentYearValueGBP' at row 127
 Rows matched: 1470  Changed: 0  Warnings: 5
```

In MySQL 5.7.14 with SQL mode "`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`", the same query is creating the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''
```

I understand why the error is happening (because of the comparison salesdata_ExchangeRate<>'') but can anyone explain why in MySQL 5.6 even though strict mode is enabled, that the query is only producing warnings and not aborting with an error? The behaviour seems different between the two versions.

**Update 1**
Created a simple table with the following structure on both MySQL 5.6.13 and MySQL 5.7.14:

[image: Structure]

Added the following records:

[image: Records]

Running the following query reproduces the same error in MySQL 5.7.14:

```
UPDATE testtable 
SET testtable_CalculatedValue = IF(testtable_DecimalValue<>'',testtable_DecimalValue,0) 
WHERE testtable_ID > 0

Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''
```

In MySQL 5.6.13, testtable_CalculatedValue is set to 1.35 as expected.

Comment: Please dump the row in question.  And check whether the offending column(s) are `NULL`, empty string, and/or a string of spaces.

Comment: @RickJames I've added information about how to reproduce, the structure of the table and a sample row that causes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE so53868586 (
         id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
         deci  DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
         calc DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY(id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SET @@sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO so53868586 (deci)
         VALUES (1.35), (NULL), (0), (12345);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Test

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM so53868586;
+----+----------+------+
| id | deci     | calc |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 |     1.35 | NULL |
|  2 |     NULL | NULL |
|  3 |     0.00 | NULL |
|  4 | 12345.00 | NULL |
+----+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> UPDATE so53868586 SET calc = IF(deci <> 0, deci, 0)
         WHERE id > 0;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT * FROM so53868586;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | deci     | calc     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |     1.35 |     1.35 |
|  2 |     NULL |     0.00 |
|  3 |     0.00 |     0.00 |
|  4 | 12345.00 | 12345.00 |
+----+----------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

(That was using 5.6.22.)

5.7.15 got the same results, but complained about `SET @sql_mode` with

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 3135 | 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release. |
| Warning | 3090 | Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release.                                                                          |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Have I failed to reproduce your test case?

I see nothing relevant in the Changelog for 5.7.15 (or anywhere around there), but you could consider updating.  (5.7.14 was issued over 2 years ago.)